# Kindle Paperwhite suddenly stopped showing collections

Tags: kindle-paperwhite

I have been using collections just about as long as the feature has existed.  Today when I turned on my Kindle the option to show collections was grayed out.

I tried restarting the reader a couple of times, but no difference. I created a collection directly, and it then allows me to choose the alternative, but only my new collection shows up on the menu. Since I have a large number of books, sorted into about 20 collections, I REALLY need that feature!

The feature does work on my Android devices, so the collections I have created are not gone. Anyone have an idea how to get them back on my Paperwhite (newer model, with smoothe flat surface all the way to the edges).